# Expanding on PowerQuery OAuth authentication functions ( StartLogin, FinishLogin, Refresh, Logout )

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot, m

I have written a few successful Custom Connectors with OAuth functionality and the authentication process does make sense.

[I have browsed through, and know many of the Sample Data Connectors well.](https://github.com/microsoft/DataConnectors/tree/master/samples)

To me it is very clear WHAT the OAuth Authentication functions DO. My question is around the details, there is not a lot of information about HOW the auth fx work.

I'm curious if there is some knowledge I have missed which might expand on the following items:

Metadata

- For example, I know that LoginUri, CallbackUri, WindowHeight, WindowWidth and Context can be used ( I just happened to find these implemented somewhere, and are not listed in documentation I have seen ), but where is the technical doc explaining what the heck they're actually doing? I can guess, as some are obvious, but what is 'Context'? And how do I know the others are doing what I think they are?
- Am I missing any?

When / how are they triggered?

- For example, it is not clear when Logout is triggered. I have some
  guesses, but again, no technical doc I've found answers that.
- Same for Refresh; is Refresh triggered when an auth fails? Or just every
  time a refresh is kicked off?
- Can I just trigger refresh whenever I
  want?

### Question Summary:

Where is the technical document explaining all the metadata and triggering process around the login flow? [( Official Pages like this do not have information on the following. )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/handlingauthentication)

If it does not exist, what is the comprehensive list of:

- Metadata

  - Used at the end of StartLogin
  - Returned with Refresh ( and can I use it? )
  - etc.. are there others and what do they do?
- Triggers

  - When *specifically* do the various flow pieces get triggered?
  - Ex: Does Refresh get called when the token / key expires ( if so is this recorded at a metadata level?? ), or does it get triggered when the API returns an expired key code?

### Bonus general complaint:

I have the same issue with many other properties: .Publish, .Icons and items in the base ( like TestConnection ). Any additional info on those would be greatly appreciated as well.